# How to change the location of avd device to D drive in windows 10 android-studio-2022.1.1.20-windows

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

How to change the location of avd device to D drive in windows 10 android-studio-2022.1.1.20-windows I tried moving the folder to d drive but then the emulator gets deleted Can you please help me to do that? a .andriod folder gets created in my Username folder

I am using Windows 10 machine with latest verison of andirod studio